# Returning Mono<UpdateResult> with Reactive MongoDB template

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, project-reactor

I am trying to get an UpdateResult in a reactive way using MongoDB reactive template in Spring Boot.

The problem is that the update part won't execute as I am not subscribing to it, but I don't really know how to do the 2 operations and returning one value with the reactive paradigm.

This is what I am trying:

```
@GetMapping("\update")
public Mono<UpdateResult> updateTask(@RequestParam(name="taskId") {
    Mono<UpdateResult> updateResult = mongoReactiveTemplate
            .findById(taskId, Task.class)
            .flatmap(object -> mongoReactiveTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(... the query), new Update().set("something", Task.class)));

    return updateresult;
}
```

The flatMap updateFirst wont happen as I am not subscribing, but I need to return the UpdateResult, if I subscribe im not sure how to return that value.

Comment: You should be able to merge the find and updates on the server with a single operation e.g. updateMulti

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller 'subscribes' the stream, so returning `Mono<UpdateResult>` is perfectly fine and will work as expected - http client will get the serialized update result.

Comment: Yes, it subscribes to the main stream, but does it too to the stream inside the flatMap? The problem is that the update is not executing and the controller keeps waiting for a return a long time (untill it throws an error for not getting anything back)

Comment: Yes, stream inside flatmap is also subsribed. Reactor API is constructed in such way, that its usually visible that you did something wrong ;) e.g. If you would use map instead flatmap, you would get `Mono<Mono<Result>>` and inner Mono wouldn't be subsribed.